# Exact signed distance function of a rhombic dodecahedron

Tags: opengl, glsl, raytracing, raymarching

I'm playing around with a ray marcher engine with voxels shaped as [rhombic dodecahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedron) since they can tessallate the 3D space perfectly like hexagons do for the 2D space.
The thing is that I only managed to come up with an approximation of the [signed distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) for that solid. It's okay to render the voxels but it gives really sharp edges. I would like to make them look better with some rounded edges using an exact SDF.

**Does anyone know the exact SDF of a rhombic dodecaheron ?**

Here's my (not exact) SDF :

```
float Sdf(Voxel voxel, vec3 position) {
    position = position - voxel.Position;
    // Exploit the solid's symmetries
    position = vec3(abs(position.x), sign(position.z) * position.y, abs(position.z));

    // distance to each face
    float a = dot(vec3(1.  ,   0.           , 0.          ), position) - voxelSize;
    float b = dot(vec3(0.5 ,   0.           , sqrt3 / 2.  ), position) - voxelSize;
    float c = dot(vec3(0.  , - sqrt2 / sqrt3, 1. / sqrt3  ), position) - voxelSize;
    float d = dot(vec3(0.5 ,   sqrt2 / sqrt3, sqrt3 / 6.  ), position) - voxelSize;
    float e = dot(vec3(0.5 , - sqrt2 / sqrt3, - sqrt3 / 6.), position) - voxelSize;

    return max(a, max(b, max(c, max(d, e))));
}
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image: img]

**EDIT :**

So I had some new ideas on how to approach this problem. In this new technique, I try to find the different areas that would have different distance formulas (depending on whether the closest point to the solid is on a face, an edge or a vertex) and compute their distance separately. So far, I only have a correct separation and distance for the areas where the closest point is on a face or on an edge.
The code looks like this :

```
float Sdf(Voxel voxel, vec3 position){
    position = position - voxel.Position;

    vec3 normals[6];
    float dists[6];
    float signs[6];

    // The rhombic dodecahedron has 6 pairs of opposite faces.
    // Assign a normal to each pair of faces.
    normals[0] = vec3(1.  ,   0.           , 0.          );
    normals[1] = vec3(0.5 ,   0.           , sqrt3 / 2.  );
    normals[2] = vec3(0.5 ,   0.           , - sqrt3 / 2.);
    normals[3] = vec3(0.  , - sqrt2 / sqrt3, 1. / sqrt3  );
    normals[4] = vec3(0.5 ,   sqrt2 / sqrt3, sqrt3 / 6.  );
    normals[5] = vec3(0.5 , - sqrt2 / sqrt3, - sqrt3 / 6.);

    // Compute the distance to each face (the sign tells which face of the pair of faces is closest)
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        dists[i] = dot(normals[i], position);
        signs[i] = sign(dists[i]);
        dists[i] = max(0., abs(dists[i]) - voxelSize);
    }

    bool sorted = false;
    while(!sorted){
        sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (dists[i] < dists[i+1]){
                vec3 n = normals[i];
                float d = dists[i];
                float s = signs[i];
                normals[i] = normals[i+1];
                dists[i] = dists[i+1];
                signs[i] = signs[i+1];
                normals[i+1] = n;
                dists[i+1] = d;
                signs[i+1] = s;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (dists[1] < dists[0] * 0.5){ //0.5 comes from sin(pi/6)
        // case where the closest point is on a face
        return dists[0];
    }
    else if (dists[2] == 0.){
        // case where the closest point is on an edge
        float a = 0.5 * dists[0];
        float b = 0.5 * (dists[1] - a);
        return length((dists[0] - b) * signs[0] * normals[0]
                    + (dists[1] - a) * signs[1] * normals[1]);
    }
    else {
        //dunno
    }
}
```

Here's a quick sketch to show how my approach[image: sketch]

The remaining cases get crazier. I'll update the post if any breakthroughs are make.

Comment: each face of your voxel has different offset ... so you need to divide the faces into groups sharing the same vertex. Then test those with `dot(point-shared_face_vertex,face_normal)` and remember the min or max or whatever you need... however what do you mean by signed? that would make sense if you have ray not just point

Comment: This seams to be a good starting point indeed. I will look into it and update any new breakthroughs.
By signed, I mean that if my point is inside the primitive, the function returns the distance to the surface, but negative. I don't really use it in this project but it come naturally by the way I implemented this simple version of the distance function.

Comment: check [Cone to box collision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214) in there look for closest between point and convex_mesh ... it might help you a lot

Comment: ah that makes sense now ... you should add the SDF definition into your question for others to see right away (not everyone is reading all the comments).

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

Assume the rhombic dodecahedron is oriented as [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVYKW.png).

This orientation makes it be symmetric with respect to mirroring along all three coordinate planes.

What you then need, is an sdf that works for [this shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FZmW.png) in the (+, +, +) octant.

**Alternative approximation**

The shape can be seen as the union of three planes.
Utilising the manhattan distance, it it possible to define an alternative to the approximated sdf:

```
float Sdf(float3 position, float size)
{
    position = abs(position);

    float halfsqrt2 = sqrt(2) / 2;

    float side1 = (position.x + position.y - size) * halfsqrt2;
    float side2 = (position.x + position.z - size) * halfsqrt2;
    float side3 = (position.y + position.z - size) * halfsqrt2;

    return max(max(side1, side2), side3);
}
```

This can be abbreviated to:

```
float Sdf(float3 position, float size)
{
    position = abs(position);

    return (max(max(position.x + position.y, position.x + position.z), position.y + position.z) - size) * sqrt(2) / 2;
}
```

**Exact sdf**

The shape can also be seen as a [transformed cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLyCn.png).
The matrices to transform from one to the other are

```
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

and it's inverse

```
-0.5  0.5  0.5
 0.5 -0.5  0.5
 0.5  0.5 -0.5
```

(There is multiple matrices that work, but this is the one I used)

After transforming, it is possible to use the sdf of a rounded box.
Here is a code example:

```
float SdfRoundRhombicDodecahedron(float3 position, float size, float edgeSize)
{
    float3x3 w2r = float3x3(
        0, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 0
    );

    position = abs(position);
    position = mul(w2r, position);
    position -= clamp(position, 0, size - edgeSize);
    return length(position) - edgeSize;
}
```

The transformed and mirrored rounded cube then has the shape of a rhombic dodecahedron.
[Here is a visualisation of it made in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7xnw.png)