# Intersection of a ray with a segment in 3d

Tags: c++, math, raycasting, plane, ray

Ray and segment of polygon lie in the same plane. The normal vector of this plane is known. I need to know if a ray intersects this segment

Comment: Hi CPPser, could you provide some more information? A segment is defined as a section of a line? or a part of a plane? make the relations clear. In this case, an image as sketch might be useful

Comment: Hi, It is segment of polygon)

Comment: How is your polygon stored? Do you have a container (vector, list, etc) containing the edges or corners?

Comment: a possible way to solve it would be searching the intersections between edges of the polygon and the ray. If it intersects any edge, you have a hit (assuming that they are in the same plane, otherwise it doesn't work that easy)

Comment: Intersection of segments in 3d is somehow unreliable. Due to rounding issues, they may not intersect even if they should mathematically. A more reliable approach is to determine the points with closest distance. (If these segments are in a plane the distance between these points should be very small - just the amount caused by rounding issues.)  Another approach could be to project the segments into 2d using the plane normal as projection vector. Then you can do a (much more reliable) 2d intersection.

Comment: exactly you need to account for the rounding errors... see [Cone to box collision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214) and look for `line closest(line l0,axis  a0);` it will return the 2 closest points between line and ray in 3D so simply compute the distance between them and if less than threshold you found your intersection)

Answer (score 2):

Choose the largest component of plane normal and make projection onto corresponding plane OXY, OXZ or OYZ (in general we can use any non-zero component)

Say Z-component is the largest, so make projection onto OXY plane. This projection is very simple - just use X and Y components. You have rather simple 2d problem now. ([Example for line segments intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect/565282#565282)).