# Ray to Octree Intersection for boolean geometry

Tags: c++, algorithm, 3d, octree

I'm trying to do boolean geometry that I have two meshes and would like to compute the intersection between them.

So I construct an octree from mesh A, and I check the vertices from mesh B against the octants, if there is an intersection, check the octant triangles for intersection, then I add the triangles, construct a mesh.

```
auto intersected_octant_faces = mn::buf_new<musa::Triangle>();
    std::stack < cg::Octant *> stack;
    stack.push(octree_sphere.root);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tri_mesh_cube.vertices.count; i++)
    {
        while (!stack.empty())
        {
            cg::Octant* node = stack.top();
            if (!node)
                break;
            stack.pop();

            musa::Ray ray;
            ray.origin = { tri_mesh_cube.vertices[i] };
            ray.dir = { 1,0,0 };

            musa::Intersection_Points pts = {};
            pts = musa::ray_box_intersection(ray, node->region);
            if (pts.count >= 1)
            {
                musa::Intersection_Points t = {};
                auto vertices = node->faces;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < vertices.count; j += 3)
                {
                    musa::Triangle tri{ vertices[j], vertices[j + 1], vertices[j + 2] };
                    t = musa::ray_triangle_intersection(ray, tri);
                    if (t.count == 1)
                    {
                        mn::buf_push(intersected_octant_faces, tri);
                    }
                }

            }
            for (auto& n : node->octants)
            {
                stack.push(n);
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now I get just two faces as shown in the figure and not sure where is the problem.
[image]

**Update:**

I have followed the algorithm that Spektre says, and that's the result:

```
auto tri_mesh_a = cg::trimesh_from_indexed_mesh(sphere_indexed_mesh);
    auto tri_mesh_b = cg::trimesh_from_indexed_mesh(cube_indexed_mesh);
    auto octree_a = cg::octree_from_mesh(tri_mesh_a);
    
        std::stack < cg::Octant*> stack;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < tri_mesh_b.vertices.count; i += 3)
        {
            musa::Triangle triB{ tri_mesh_b.vertices[i], tri_mesh_b.vertices[i + 1], tri_mesh_b.vertices[i + 2] };
            stack.push(octree_a.root);

            while (!stack.empty())
            {
                cg::Octant* node = stack.top();
                stack.pop();

                if (box_box_intersect(musa::triangle_bounding_box(triB), node->region))
                {
                    auto vertices = node->faces;

                    for (size_t a = 0; a < vertices.count; a += 3)
                    {
                        musa::Triangle triA{ vertices[a], vertices[a + 1], vertices[a + 2] };

                        if (triangle_triangle_intersection_check(triB, triA))
                        {
                            vec3 v1 = { vertices[a] };
                            vec3 v2 = { vertices[a + 1] };
                            vec3 v3 = { vertices[a + 2] };

                            mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, v1);
                            mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, v2);
                            mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, v3);


                        }



                    }

                    for (auto& n : node->octants)
                    {
                        if (n == nullptr)
                            continue;
                        stack.push(n);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

 
    for (int i = 0; i < self->modelIntersection.points.count; i++)
    {
        mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.indices, i);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let assume: sphere is object `A` and the Octree `o` is populated with it. The cube is object `B` and both objects are constructed from only triangles.

1. **for each triangle of `B`**

   so loop through all triangles of `B` and test one at a time let call it `tb`. Let call the triangle points: `tb.p0, tb.p1, t.p2`
2. **obtain all `o` nodes intersecting `tb` triangle**

   In case your Octree does not have triangle testing you can simplify by testing lines:

   ```
   line(tb.p0,tb.p1)
   line(tb.p1,tb.p2)
   line(tb.p2,tb.p0)
   ```

   Its not complete test but in most cases its enough. You can also test few inside lines to cover some interior if needed:

   ```
   pp = (tb.p0 + tb.p1 + tb.p2) / 3
   line(tb.pp,tb.p0)
   line(tb.pp,tb.p1)
   line(tb.pp,tb.p2)
   ```

   However if you need full test you would most likely need to implement it the hard way (triangle vs cube intersection).
3. **for each found intersecting node test all its triangles against `tb`**

   So now you do triangle from `A` versus triangle `tb` test and store all triangles from `A` that intersects.

   Here example of the full test: [`line closest(triangle t0,triangle t1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214)

   There will be probably many duplicate triangles in the result so you might add a duplicity test before adding new triangle to the result.

Comment: It does now intersect good, but there are triangles that are not included, another that are excluded.