# Cone normal vector

Tags: graphics, geometry, raytracing

I have **cone->p** (vertex of the cone), **cone->orient** (axis vector), **cone->k** (half-angle tangent), **cone->minm** and **cone->maxm** (2 height values, for cone caps). Also I have point **intersection** which is on the cone. How do I find the cone (side surface) normal vector at **intersection** point using only these parameters?

Comment: not an answer to your problem but see [Cone to box collision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214) for some inspiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сame up with simpler method:

Find distance `Dis` from intersection point `I` to base `P`

Make axis orientation vector of length

```
D = Dis * sqrt(1+k^2)
```

and make point on axis at this distance

```
A = P + Normalized(Orient) * D
```

Now

```
Normal = I - A
```

[image]

---

Old answer:
Make orthogonal projection of point `I` (intersection) onto cone axis using vector `IP = I - P' and scalar (dot) product:

```
AxProj = P + Orient * dot(IP, Orient) / dot(Orient, Orient)
```

Vector from `AxPr` to `I` (perpendicular to axis):

```
AxPerp = I - AxProj
```

Vector, tangent to cone surface, using vector product:

```
T = IP x AxPerp
```

Vector, normal to cone surface:

```
N = T x IP
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If `I` is the intersection point on the cone's surface and you know its coordinates, and `P` is the vertex of the cone, whose coordinates you also know, then this is enough:

```
Normal = (axis x PI) x PI
Normal = Normal / norm(Normal)
```

where `axis` is the vector aligned with the axis of the cone.