# How to find projection of a point on a line

Tags: math, graphics, line, point, projection

How can I find projection of a point p=(x, y, z) on the line l(t)= q + vt?
where v is the unit norm vector, and q is a point on the line

Comment: what projection ? if perpendicular then simple dot product `dot(p-q,v)` will give you the distance to `q` see [`line closest(point p0,axis a0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214). Funny I just made similar comment pointing to this for slightly different reason just a minute ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From this sketch, if we define define the vectors **q** = **OQ** and **p** = **OP**, then the orthogonal projection of **p** onto **v** is the component of **p** that follows the direction of **v**.

Or more explicitly, it's the vector ((**p** · **v**)/**v**²) · **v** = (**p** · **v**) · **v**, since **v**² = 1.

Comment: the `v²` should be `|v²|` however commonmark breaks the bold formatting if I add it ... also `p` should be relative to `q` so `((p-q).v)` in respect to OP notation.

Comment: Hi @Spektre, **v²** and |v|² are equivalent, since **v²** = **v** · **v** = vvcos(0) = |v|². Also, please note that the unit vector **v** has already implicit **q** on it, since **v** = (**q'** - **q**)/(| **q'** - **q** |²) for some **q'**. The vector **p** is given and its coordinates are relative to O(0, 0, 0), not from **q** (why would you modify it by **p** - **q**?), The vector you say, ((**p** - **q**) · **v**) · **v**, is the projection of **p** - **r** onto **v**, but not the one of **p** onto **v**, which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Ahh English math notation ... when I look at `v²` I did not see its `(v.v)` ...  I see no mention in OP about `p` is already relative to `q` but if the case you're right.