# Find max radius of an arc between two lines in 3D

Tags: c#, math, vector, trigonometry

I have found this solution to draw an arc between two points in 3D.
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71363024/calculate-3d-arc-from-three-vectors-and-a-given-radius/75428653?noredirect=1#comment133089510_75428653)

Can anyone help to find a way how two limit the radius so the arc starts at max half distance of the shorter line

[image: half way ogf P2P3]

I have tried some simple geometry method of finding hal of angle between the lines and then calc the radius from r = tan(half_angle) but this works only for an angle close to 45 deg.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum radius of an arc between two lines in 3D depends on the distance between the lines and the angle between them. The radius of the arc is given by:     code example :
r = (d / 2) / sin(theta / 2)

Where d is the distance between the lines, and theta is the angle between the lines. The radius r is the maximum possible radius of the arc that can be formed between the lines, such that the arc lies in the plane that is perpendicular to the direction vectors of both lines and bisects the angle between the lines.